# When I dismiss the modal window, I see the navigation bar of the previous window

Tags: ios, swift, navbar, swipe, navigationcontroller

I'm using [SwipeViewController](https://github.com/fortmarek/SwipeViewController). I asked my question to the developer, but he ignores it. [Here is my question](https://github.com/fortmarek/SwipeViewController/issues/28).

When I close modal within dismiss method of ImagePicker

`imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Navigation bar from SwipeVC  is displayed instead of VC1 navigation bar.

Do you have any ideas how to deal with that or what am I doing wrong?

gif problem :
[image]

Comment: do you add the 3 custom elements to your toolbar in the `viewWillAppear(_:)` method? if yes, just don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **SwipeViewController** is a subclass of **UINavigationController** and in the library they're adding the titleView(Which you say that is displaying) to the navigation Item.

What you can do is edit the source of the Library and move the `setSwipeViewController()` function into ViewDidLoad.

or

What you can do is take a boolean in **SwipeViewController**

```
var isSetupNeeded: Bool = true
```

and set it to **true** when you're presenting your **imagePickerController**. And in **ViewWillAppear** of **SwipeVIewController** set a condition that

```
if self.isSetupNeeded { 
    self.setSwipeViewController()
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, but there is a problem when I transfer to viewDidLoad - the boot sequence is this: 1)SwipeViewController viewDidLoad 2)VC: SwipeViewController viewDidLoad. 
And because of this pageArray in SwipeViewController is empty. 
And if you call setSwipeViewController () after filling the array in the ViewController, then the application does not crash, but the navigation bar is not drawn

Comment: @RuslanMikailov Edited the answer!!

Comment: @RuslanMikailov Great!! Happy Coding!!